# Regex in Mongodb for ISO Date field

Tags: regex, mongodb

How can I pick all the dates with time value as 00:00:00 despite the date value? Regex doesn't work for me.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59115a92bbf6401d4455eb21"),
    "name" : "sfdfsdfsf",
    "create_date" : ISODate("2013-05-13T02:34:23.000Z"),
}
```

something like :

```
db.myCollection.find({"create_date": /*T00:00:00.000Z/ })
```

Comment: Give me the reason for down vote. I can't find solution on stackoverflow. and the provided solution doen't work for me. Do you have any reason for downvote?

Comment: this one is also not working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412761/querying-embedded-documents-by-matching-dates-in-mongodb

Comment: Not sure if this suits you, but you can do this using aggregation

Comment: My requirement is to find all the records with create time 00:00:00 (from combination of date and time) and update them. Even for aggregation I need to find a way to pick those records. Regex seems the solution but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first convert created date into string of time, and if time is 00:00:00:000, then include the document.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  // Part 1: Project all fields and add timeCriteria field that contain only time(will be used to match 00:00:00:000 time)
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "$name",
      create_date: "$create_date",
      timeCriteria: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%H:%M:%S:%L",
          date: "$create_date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Part 2: match the time
  {
    $match: {
      timeCriteria: {
        $eq: "00:00:00:000"
      }
    }
  },
  // Part 3: re-project document, to exclude timeCriteria field.
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "$name",
      create_date: "$create_date"
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB version >= 4.4 we can write custom filters using [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator.

**Note**: Donot forget to chage the timezone to your requirement. Timezone is not mandatory.

```js
let timeRegex = /.*T00:00:00.000Z$/i;

db.myCollection.find({
  $expr: {
    $function: {
      body: function (createDate, timeRegex) {
        return timeRegex.test(createDate);
      },
      args: [{ $dateToString: { date: "$create_date", timezone: "+0530" } }, timeRegex],
      lang: "js"
    }
  }
});
```